# Using Lagrange multipliers for inner points?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I would like your help to determine whether there is a fault in my reasoning.

Let's say that we have the following shape in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$B=\\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^4+y^4+z^4 \le 1\\}$

Some unknown function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, that is defined everywhere and is $C^3$, has a maximum point in $B$, off the axes.

I define the following Lagrange multiplier problem, for every $0\lt R\lt 1$:

$\begin{cases}
\text{ext.}& f(x,y,z) \\\\
\text{s.t.}& B_R(x,y,z)=x^4+y^4+z^4-R=0
\end{cases}$

The solution of such problem is $Df(x,y,z)=\lambda DB_R(x,y,z)$

Therefore $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lambda\cdot 4x^3$, etc.

If we derive a second time, we get $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=12\lambda x^2, \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}=0$, etc.

So the Hessian matrix for a max point $u$ of $f$ in $B$, which is in radius $R$, is defined because it is an inner point, and is supposedly known as:
$Hess(f)(u)=diag(12\lambda x^2,12\lambda y^2,12\lambda z^2)$

The Hessian is positive definite, so $u$ cannot be a maximum point.

The only possibility left is that the maximum point is received on $\partial B$ (the surface of B), where a Hessian is not defined over B.

Is this a valid usage of Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: First, the method of lagrange multipliers gives the stationary points (minima, maxima, saddle). Second to classify a stationary point in this context, we need to use the **bordered** hessian.